# JQueryMobile filtering a XMLhttprequest

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery-mobile

I am having difficults to get the JQueryMobile filter function working on the script that I am using.

I have created a simple xmlhttp request to collect the data from an XML file with 175 entries and 4 columns. The output is ok. Now I wan't to filter inside this table. But when hooking up the  it has no effect.

Any help is appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","Issue.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;


    document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">')
    var Asset = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Attribute");

     for (x = 0; x <= Asset.length; x++)    //Asset.length
            {
            document.write("<tr>");
              document.write("<td>" + xmlDoc.getElementsByName("Number")[x].childNodes[0].nodeValue)  + "</td>"; 
              document.write("<td>" + xmlDoc.getElementsByName("Name")[x].childNodes[0].nodeValue)  + "</td>"; 
              document.write("<td>" + xmlDoc.getElementsByName("Address")[x].childNodes[0].nodeValue)  + "</td>"; 
              document.write("<td>" + xmlDoc.getElementsByName("Phone")[x].childNodes[0].nodeValue)  + "</td>"; 
            document.write("</tr>");
            }

    document.write("</table>");
  </script>
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Assets pageSize="2222222" pageStart="0" total="175">
<Asset href="www.home1.com">
    <Attribute name="Number">123123123</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Name">asdqweqweqwe</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Address">dsffdfsdfdasfsda</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Phone">123123123</Attribute>
</Asset>
<Asset href="www.home2.com">
    <Attribute name="Number">4344433</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Name">ssssss</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Address">ddddd</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Phone">6666666</Attribute>
</Asset>
</Asset>
```

Working Table header:

```
    document.write('<table data-role="table" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterTable-input" id="thetable" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">');
    document.write('<thead><tr><th>Number</th><th>Name</th><th>Custom</th><th>Owner</th></tr></thead>');
    document.write('<tbody>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing the jQuery Mobile widgets (table and filterable) after creating the table.  Here is an example of how to do it.

Given a jQM page with a filter input and an empty container for the table:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form>
            <input id="filterTable-input" data-type="search" />
        </form>
        <div id="tableContainer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your script would create the table with `data-filter="true"` and `data-input="#filterTable-input"`, go ahead and create the THEAD and TBODY sections and fill in the rows using your XML. After appending the created table to the empty container, initialize the table and filterable widgets using `.table()` and `.filterable()`:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){      
    var thetable = '<table data-role="table" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterTable-input" id="thetable" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">';    
    thetable += '<thead><tr><th>Number</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Address</th></tr></thead>';
    thetable += '<tbody>';
    for (x = 0; x <= 175; x++)  {
        thetable += '<tr>';
        thetable += '<td>' + x + 'a</td>'
        thetable += '<td>' + x + 'b</td>'
        thetable += '<td>' + x + 'c</td>'
        thetable += '<td>' + x + 'd</td>'
        thetable += '</tr>';
    }
    thetable += '</tbody>';
    thetable += '</table>';

    $("#tableContainer").empty().append(thetable);    
    $("#thetable").table().filterable( );
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8sLBK/1/)**

Comment: Ok, but that won't allow me to work with the XML file, correct?

Comment: Here is how my xml looks like.

Comment: Yes you can work with the XML, I was just keeping the example simple so you would see the filter work. In your case just build the table on the success portion of your ajax call by iterating through the XML as in your original code.

Comment: Thanks for all you help so far ezanker.
Being newbie makes thinks drag a lot longer what it should :)
I couldn't manage to associate the rows of my XML into your sample code. Also, I am not sure which field should be modified in order to make it work.
Basically, on my call I know that I am calling each Attribute assigned to a particular Asset # before going to the next line, and that loops go for the length of assets presented on the XML file which is called by the line xmlhttp.open("GET","Issue.xml",false);
I can't translate it to my understanding so then I can figure what each line is doing

Comment: Here is my code working as it is now. @ezanker What should I modify using your example 

http://jsfiddle.net/saulofaria/2GP9g/27/

Comment: Ok. I have worked with a friend and he clarifid to me what you have pointed as being the problem.

We have to only modify the table structure and now it's filtering capabilities.

Thanks

Comment: I assume from your last comment that you have it figured out now.